# Deleting the exact object in array when value is false

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My code looks like this:

```
var data = someDataWhichComesFromOtherMethod
var array = [
    {name: "one", value:"data1", caption:"aaa"...},
    {name: "two", value:"data2", caption:"bbb"...},
    {name: "three", value:"data3", caption:"ccc"...},
    {name: "four", value:"data4", caption:"ddd"...}
    ...
]
```

What I want to do is to: first check if the `array` is not empty and later check if incoming `data` is true or not and when it's not, whole object needs to be deleted from the array.

I started with:

```
if (array && array.length) {
    //true
} else {
    //false
}
```

For example, if `data4` is `null` or `""`, `array` should look like this:

```
var array = [
    {name: "one", value:"data1", caption:"aaa"...},
    {name: "two", value:"data2", caption:"bbb"...},
    {name: "three", value:"data3", caption:"ccc"...}
    ...
]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"if data4 is false"*? Does that mean not existing or it has some property that is `false`?

Comment: I meant, for example, it's empty (`null` or `""`)

Comment: What specifically is empty?? Will get a lot more help by providing a [mcve]

Comment: Where is your code that shows what you have tried so far? If can't provide that then this question would just be open to opinion as there are a number of ways (filter, reduce, loop, etc).

Comment: Add examples of `false` values to your `array` variable

Comment: As i wrote before, `data` is someDataWhichComesFromOtherMethod, so it doesn't depend on me. But I think the `string` should come, so the opposite would be `""`.

Comment: That still doesn't help explain what a `null` `data4` is or looks like. Do you mean if `value` is `null` or an empty string?

Comment: Well, if `data4` is empty string or null, value would be the same, right...? I wrote a few times that I am not sure what `value` would be, because it comes "from the outside", so it can be both. But it's only the matter of a condition, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test the value of `value` and remove the item from the array when it is `falsey`, you could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the items that are `truthy`.

```js
var array = [
    {name: "one", value:"data1", caption:"aaa"},
    {name: "two", value:"data2", caption:"bbb"},
    {name: "three", value:"data3", caption:"ccc"},
    {name: "four", value:null, caption:"ddd"},
    {name: "five", value:"", caption:"eee"}
]

var result = array.filter(item => item.value)

console.log(result);
```